# Split a string into an array with undefined whitespaces

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have this data that I'm trying to split up into separate parts, the only problem is is that the whitespaces in between each value isn't the same. For example:

```
2010   1    5.1     0.9      11    55.4    86.1#
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String[] values = input.split("\\s+");
```

Rolf

Answer (score 0):

Tokenize the string, then remove whitespace.  I will leave the implementation up to you in case this is homework.